# Jquery variable in selector not selecting the div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Here are the lines in my function that should be selecting the div

```
var t=1;
var problemId=1234;
var x="#problemTypeDtl&" +t+"_"+problemId;
$(x).Text('bites');
```

Here is the div:

```
 <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
       <div class="problemStatusType" id="problemTypeDtl&1_1234"></div>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

It looks like the the selector is not selecting the div...what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pretty sure the ampersand in your div ID is not legal (depending on your doctype) which would in turn break any use of `getElementById()`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html/79022#79022

Comment: Definitely illegal: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-AttValue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you make an all encompassing class called `problemTypeDt` along with `problemStatusType` (because I don't know if you need to keep that for something else) and use the problem ID as well...an ID. So

Script

```
var t=1;
var problemId=1234;
var x=t+"_"+problemId;
$("div.problemTypeDt#"+x).Text('bites');
```

Markup

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
       <div class="problemStatusType problemTypeDt" id="problemTypeDtl&1_1234"></div>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

As noted above in the comments, it is illegal to use an ampersand.

Answer (score 2):

Try escaping the ampersand:

```
var x="#problemTypeDtl\\&" +t+"_"+problemId;
```